# Is there a way to run go tests on save in VSCode, and output it to the terminal?

Tags: go, testing, visual-studio-code

Right now I have a few projects I'm running in VSCode, and it's quite tedious to run `go test` everytime I write new code, I'd rather see if I broke something right away. I know in Javascript I am able to run the tests everytime I save a file, and have the output sent to the terminal.

Right now I am using a "[run on save](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emeraldwalk.RunOnSave)" extension, and I have a config file that looks like:

```
{
    "emeraldwalk.runonsave": {
        "commands": [
            {
                "match": ".*",
                "cmd": " go test"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

But it outputs to the "output" section of VSCode, and I'd like it to output to my terminal.

So is there either:

1. A way to have this extension output to my terminal
2. A way to have "go test" run on a loop whenever I save?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: related _general_ question (I wouldn't say this question is a dup of it): [Auto run tests in Visual Studio Code](/q/72041831/11107541)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is supported by the Go extension.

Go to Settings => Go, and there is an explicit option for this: "Test on Save".

To see the test result, select the "Go Tests" in the output.

Comment: Thanks. I guess that might be what I have to do. I guess my next question would be how to get the output sent to the terminal?

Comment: @PatrickCollins The "Output" view is next to the terminal. Select the output, not the terminal. Once you do that, on the right there's a drop-down list to select which output do you want to see: the output of go tests.

Comment: Thank you, I meant I wanted to combine the terminal and the output, but that sounds like a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

If your intent is to watch code and run tests in an automated manner, then checkout [GoConvey](https://smartystreets.github.io/goconvey/). It is amazing. Else, you can use [Trigger Task on Save](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gruntfuggly.triggertaskonsave) VSCode extension for this.

Comment: The GoConvey link appears to be broken.

Comment: Fixed the link to GoConvey