# Auto run tests in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I run the tests automatically in visual studio code? My project has testing setup, and the settings JSON/UI has settings related to auto running tests, but I don't see an option for the test to actually run automatically. I have found topics around this issue, but those seem to be out of date, or related to a (different) plugin.

[settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfRxH.png)

Answer (score 3):

In complement to the answer provided by @DanCiborowski, I would use the extension RunItOn instead of the RunOnSave because it is possible to run internal VSCode commands. Like so, the output from `pytest` is correctly integrated in the VSCode IDE.

Once RunItOn is installed, you can configure it with the settings:

```
"runItOn": {
        "commands": [
            {
                "match": "\\.py$",
                "isAsync": true,
                "isShellCommand": false,
                "cmd": "testing.runAll"
            },
        ],
    },
```

I've prepared a step-by-step tutorial here:
https://cordmaur.medium.com/how-to-autorun-python-tests-in-vscode-step-by-step-cfb24c6fc4be

Answer (score 1):

The Python support for VSCode is an extension, which does not fully support "all" the testing features. The "Testing > Auto Run" settings are currently missing. This issue is being tracked here.
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/19046

Until this feature is properly implemented, the best way to achieve this uses extensions such as "Run on Save", the most popular item in the marketplace.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emeraldwalk.RunOnSave

```
"emeraldwalk.runonsave": {
    "commands": [
        {
            "match": "**.py",
            "isAsync": true,
            "cmd": "pytest"
        }
    ]
}
```

(disclosure, I work for MSFT and was investigating this issue prior to finding the question while doing my own research on alternatives)

Answer (score 1):

As for VS Code with no extensions, it has a Continuous Run API, which was requested in [issue ticket #134941](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/134941) and added in [Pull Request #176454](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/176454). Some related API docs can be found in the docs for [`TestController`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TestController), [`TestRunProfile`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TestRunProfile), and [`TestRunRequest`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TestRunRequest). There's a related user setting with ID `testing.autoRun.delay` to control debouncing. So if whatever extension you're using which contributes the testing support using the VS Code API supports feature using this API, then you will have it.

The Go extension seems to have its own thing. See [Is there a way to run go tests on save in VSCode, and output it to the terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61334087/11107541).

Comment: So there is an API for it, but no setting? Even if an extension were to support this, wouldn't there still need to be standard way for the user to indicate they want the tests to run after every file save or something like that, and it would have to work with the standard Testing panel that is typically used.

Answer (score 0):

Since VSCode is a text editor rather than a fully-fledged IDE, tests are not a native feature. Testing frameworks also vary drastically between different programming languages or environments. I'd suggest looking into command-line tools such [`jest`](https://jestjs.io/) for JavaScript which you can run via VSCode's integrated terminal.

Another approach is to create a custom [task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) to run your test. Find an example for `jest` [here](https://dev.to/nalanj/vscode-task-for-jest-40jk).

Comment: I was mainly looking for a convenient way to just rerun the tests whenever I save a file. It's also very strange that there are builtin options when you autorun tests (which tests to autorun, and a delay), but no way to actual autorun. Why are there options for a feature which doesn't exist?

Some more details: I already can run tests, both on the commandline, and in VSCode. The main thing I was looking for is to autorun the tests as the code I'm currently working on is really suitable for TDD. I'm using py.test btw.